# Tomcat: Where to locate Tomcat Lib Folder

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, debian

I am trying to install the JDBC driver on my tomcat installation, but I'm having a hard time. I installed Tomcat to my opt/tomcat directory.

I was then told to put the JDBC driver into my /lib folder but I cant find it in the opt/tomcat directory. Do I have to make it if it doesnt exist, or am I just not looking in the right place?

Comment: Why do you want to put the driver in the Tomcat lib directory? In general, it is better to ship it with your web application that you're deploying.

Comment: @SJuan76 Currently I am using Tomcat v6.0.35

Comment: @KristofferE I am running SOLR on tomcat and SOLR needs it to connect to my postgresql database on another server.

Comment: @KristofferE I disagree, you app just should ask the framework (let it be the server or hibernate) the connection and do not know which database it is dealing with. The server or hibernate then may be configured to use whatever is more convenient.

Comment: This link confirms that you are looking for it in the right place ($CATALINA_HOME) is the installation directory. Maybe a botched install? http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Shared_Library_Files

Comment: How did you install tomcat? Did you use apt-get on Debian? Could the install be split and it have landed somewhere else like /usr/share/tomcat# as is referenced in [this article?](http://sebthom.de/142-installing-tomcat-6-debian-squeeze/) [Note, I don't run Debian, and I often "install" tomcat by just unzipping it and starting it up...]

Comment: James can you show an listing of the /opt/tomcat

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer my own question. I actually built it from source and catalina home was specified in a different directory, not opt/tomcat. When I found this directory I found the lib folder and dumped the file in there.

Thank you all for the help, I upvoted as many as I could.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue while trying to install the **drizzle-jdbc** jar connector on my tomcat installation.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

Run the command below to determine the location of your `tomcat` installation:

```
sudo find / -name "tomcat"
```

For me the output was:

```
/opt/tomcat
/tmp/tomcat
```

Then, using the output, change into the `/opt/tomcat` directory:

```
cd /opt/tomcat
```

Next, list the contents of the `/opt/tomcat` directory:

```
ls /opt/tomcat
```

For me the output was:

```
bin  conf  lib  LICENSE  logs  NOTICE  RELEASE-NOTES  RUNNING.txt  temp  webapps  work
```

You can then change into the lib directory:

```
cd lib
```

Now you can copy your jar files into the `lib` directory.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**